# How to use Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE); in mPDF v.6.1.4?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf, php-5.6, php4

I have an issue when calling output function using v.6.1.4.
Since i've ever tried to use `Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE);` function in mPDF v.7.x so i tried this format function in mPDF v.6.1.4 (just changed "\Mpdf.." to "\mPDF..") because i am working with company that's using php 5 even older, and then i get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'mPDF\Output\Destination' not found.

How can i to perform the mPDF output function to show the pdf inline browser in mPDF v.6.1.4 ?

Thanks in Advance Brothers/Sisters.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string `I` as a second parameter, that means "inline".

```
$mpdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'I');
```

See the actual string values of the Output constants introduced in mPDF 7: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/src/Output/Destination.php

The [Mpdf::Output documentation page](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html) now also shows the actual values of helper `Mpdf\Output\Destination` class constants.

Comment: The question is about how to use `Output('filename.pdf', \Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE);` in `Mpdf v6.1.4`.

Comment: No, the question was "How can i to perform the mPDF output function to show the pdf inline browser in mPDF v.6.1.4 ?", Which I answered. Sure, I could have been even more verbose, I edited the answer with a code example.

Comment: i had ran this code brother but still downloaded the pdf instead of showing the pdf inline browser.

Comment: What is your browser? Can you display PDFs inline from another sources? Do you set HTTP headers elsewhere in the code?

Comment: i am using Chrome x78 and Firefo x68.  
Btw now whenever i want to show PDF inline browser. it would be downloaded instead of showing it in browser.
Also i have set HTTP headers on top of my code.
How can i show the PDF inline of Browser hmm. so that the user can see it content before downloading the PDF file.

Comment: I meant Chrome v78 and Firefox v68.

Comment: Do not set http headers yourself. You're probably overriding headers set my mPDF.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean about "... overriding headers set ..." sir ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `\Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE` in mPDF v.6.1.4, for class `\Mpdf\Output\Destination` is not defined in [mPDF v.6.1.4](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/tree/v6.1.4). But you can use `I` instead of `\Mpdf\Output\Destination::INLINE`.

`Class 'mPDF\Output\Destination` is defined since [mPdf v7.0.](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/tree/v7.0.0-RC1)

---

To make it more clear, the relevant source code.
Here is the source code, and there is no `/Output/Destination.php` in this version.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpdf/mpdf/v6.1.4/mpdf.php

```
function Output($name = '', $dest = '')
{

    ...
    if (is_bool($dest))
        $dest = $dest ? 'D' : 'F';
    $dest = strtoupper($dest);
    if ($dest == '') {
        if ($name == '') {
            $name = 'mpdf.pdf';
            $dest = 'I';
        } else {
            $dest = 'F';
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is the source code of v7.0.0, and  `Output/Destination.php` is added.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpdf/mpdf/v7.0.0/src/Mpdf.php

```
function Output($name = '', $dest = '')
{

    ...
    if (is_bool($dest)) {
        $dest = $dest ? Destination::DOWNLOAD : Destination::FILE;
    }

    $dest = strtoupper($dest);
    if (empty($dest)) {
        if (empty($name)) {
            $name = 'mpdf.pdf';
            $dest = Destination::INLINE;
        } else {
            $dest = Destination::FILE;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/v7.0.0/src/Output/Destination.php

```
<?php
namespace Mpdf\Output;
class Destination
{
    const FILE = 'F';
    const DOWNLOAD = 'D';
    const STRING_RETURN = 'S';
    const INLINE = 'I';
}
```

Comment: you have given the good relevant source code brother, but unfortunately the pdf still download the file instead of showing inline browser brother.

Comment: If you want to view it, you need to add `Content-Type: application/pdf` to header.

Comment: I have added `header("Content-Type: application/pdf");` right after `include "config.php";` but still download the file. Do you have any solution brother ?